# How to fix crash while moving to the google activity

Tags: java, android, google-maps, crash

I have had this problem for awhile now, I have the main activity with buttons that will take the user to another activity with the google map in the view,but if the user taps on the button the app just crashes and gives a message saying "Unfortunately,(app name) has stopped."

here is the activity with the google map:

```
package location.hive;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;


public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private static final int DIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_with_map);

        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync();

        String city = getIntent().getStringExtra("city");

        setTitle(getString(R.string.landon_hotel) + ", " + city);

        Hotel hotel = DataProvider.hotelMap.get(city);
        if (hotel == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.error_find_hotel) + ": "
                    + city, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        TextView cityText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cityText);
        cityText.setText(hotel.getCity());

        TextView neighborhoodText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.neighborhoodText);
        neighborhoodText.setText(hotel.getNeighborhood());

        TextView descText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.descriptionText);
        descText.setText(hotel.getDescription() + "\n");

        if (servicesOK() && initMap()) {

            Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);
            List<Address> list;
            try {
                list = gc.getFromLocationName(hotel.getAddress(), 1);
                Address address = list.get(0);
                double lat = address.getLatitude();
                double lng = address.getLongitude();
                LatLng latLong = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLong, 15);
                mMap.moveCamera(update);

                MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                        .title(getString(R.string.landon_hotel) + ", " + city)
                        .position(new LatLng(lat, lng));
                mMap.addMarker(options);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.error_finding_hotel), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d(this.getLocalClassName(), e.getMessage());
            }

        }

    }

    public boolean servicesOK() {
        int result = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

        if (result == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            return true;
        } else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(result)) {
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result, this, DIALOG_REQUEST);
            dialog.show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.error_connect_to_services), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean initMap() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            SupportMapFragment mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
        }
        return (mMap != null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    }

}
```

and now the main activity:

```
package location.hive;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<Hotel> hotels = DataProvider.hotelList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        ArrayAdapter<Hotel> adapter =
                new HotelAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item_location, hotels);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);

                Hotel location = hotels.get(position);
                intent.putExtra("city", location.getCity());
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });

    }

}
```

and finally the logcat:

```
02-26 14:45:07.452 27233-27233/location.hive W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/location.hive-1/lib/arm
02-26 14:45:07.472 27233-27233/location.hive I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
02-26 14:45:07.472 27233-27233/location.hive I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
02-26 14:45:07.562 27233-27233/location.hive W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/location.hive-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in location.hive rsrc of package null
02-26 14:45:07.572 27233-27233/location.hive W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/location.hive-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in location.hive rsrc of package null
02-26 14:45:07.622 27233-27233/location.hive W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
02-26 14:45:07.792 27233-27233/location.hive D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-26 14:45:07.792 27233-27233/location.hive D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-26 14:45:07.822 27233-27233/location.hive D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
02-26 14:45:07.832 27233-27233/location.hive E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = android.hardware.scontext.ISContextService$Stub$Proxy@1c027fd
02-26 14:45:07.832 27233-27233/location.hive E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@5ae4cf2
02-26 14:45:07.832 27233-27233/location.hive E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@5ae4cf2
02-26 14:45:07.862 27233-27233/location.hive D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
02-26 14:45:07.872 27233-27233/location.hive D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{7c739c0 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
02-26 14:45:07.872 27233-27276/location.hive D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
02-26 14:45:07.922 27233-27276/location.hive I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (Ia10634f51b)
                                                           OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.29.00.00
                                                           Build Date: 01/28/16 Thu
                                                           Local Branch: ss
                                                           Remote Branch: 
                                                           Local Patches: 
                                                           Reconstruct Branch: 
02-26 14:45:07.922 27233-27276/location.hive D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0x9eb9a7c4
02-26 14:45:07.922 27233-27276/location.hive I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-26 14:45:08.002 27233-27233/location.hive D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-26 14:45:08.002 27233-27233/location.hive D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-26 14:45:08.022 27233-27233/location.hive D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-26 14:45:08.022 27233-27233/location.hive D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-26 14:45:08.062 27233-27233/location.hive D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-26 14:45:08.072 27233-27233/location.hive D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-26 14:45:08.102 27233-27233/location.hive D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-26 14:45:08.102 27233-27233/location.hive D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-26 14:45:08.172 27233-27233/location.hive W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
02-26 14:45:08.192 27233-27233/location.hive W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
02-26 14:45:08.382 27233-27233/location.hive D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) or=1
02-26 14:45:08.422 27233-27233/location.hive I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@bd4af43 time:97011894
02-26 14:45:10.632 27233-27233/location.hive D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
02-26 14:45:10.682 27233-27233/location.hive D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
02-26 14:45:10.752 27233-27233/location.hive I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:location.hive time:97014225
02-26 14:45:10.822 27233-27233/location.hive W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/location.hive-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in location.hive rsrc of package null
02-26 14:45:10.832 27233-27328/location.hive W/ResourceType: For resource 0x7f02005a, entry index(90) is beyond type entryCount(2)
02-26 14:45:10.832 27233-27328/location.hive W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f02005a (t=1 e=90) (error -75)
02-26 14:45:10.842 27233-27328/location.hive E/Resources: RunTimeException
                                                          android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f02005a
                                                              at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2558)
                                                              at android.content.res.Resources.startRC(Resources.java:1116)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$mRunnable.run(ActivityThread.java:3055)
                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
02-26 14:45:10.852 27233-27233/location.hive D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-26 14:45:10.852 27233-27233/location.hive D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-26 14:45:10.852 27233-27233/location.hive D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-26 14:45:10.852 27233-27233/location.hive D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-26 14:45:10.862 27233-27233/location.hive D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-26 14:45:10.922 27233-27233/location.hive I/zzbz: Making Creator dynamically
02-26 14:45:10.942 27233-27233/location.hive I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:18
02-26 14:45:10.942 27233-27233/location.hive I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite, version >= 18
02-26 14:45:10.952 27233-27233/location.hive W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.google.android.gms-2/base.apk / 1.0 running in location.hive rsrc of package null
02-26 14:45:10.992 27233-27233/location.hive W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000030/n/armeabi
02-26 14:45:11.002 27233-27233/location.hive W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000030/DynamiteModulesB_GmsCore_prodmnc_xxhdpi_release.apk / 1.0 running in location.hive rsrc of package null
02-26 14:45:11.012 27233-27233/location.hive W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000030/DynamiteModulesB_GmsCore_prodmnc_xxhdpi_release.apk / 1.0 running in location.hive rsrc of package null
02-26 14:45:11.112 27233-27233/location.hive I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 11910000
02-26 14:45:11.132 27233-27233/location.hive I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 11975438
02-26 14:45:11.352 27233-27233/location.hive W/System.err: remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/user/0/location.hive/files/DATA_ServerControlledParametersManager.data.location.hive
02-26 14:45:11.492 27233-27233/location.hive D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
02-26 14:45:11.492 27233-27233/location.hive E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = android.hardware.scontext.ISContextService$Stub$Proxy@eb5cd14
02-26 14:45:11.492 27233-27233/location.hive E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@95c99bd
02-26 14:45:11.492 27233-27233/location.hive E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@95c99bd
02-26 14:45:11.522 27233-27233/location.hive W/System.err: mkdir failed: EEXIST (File exists) : /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/location.hive/cache/debug
02-26 14:45:11.522 27233-27233/location.hive W/System.err: mkdir failed: EEXIST (File exists) : /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/location.hive/cache
02-26 14:45:11.642 27233-27359/location.hive W/System.err: remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/user/0/location.hive/files/event_store_v2_location.hive
02-26 14:45:11.652 27233-27233/location.hive D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-26 14:45:11.652 27233-27233/location.hive E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: location.hive, PID: 27233
                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{location.hive/location.hive.DetailActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference
                                                                   at location.hive.DetailActivity.onCreate(DetailActivity.java:42)
                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
02-26 14:45:13.652 27233-27360/location.hive W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
02-26 14:45:13.662 27233-27360/location.hive I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:4
02-26 14:45:13.662 27233-27360/location.hive I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 4
02-26 14:45:13.682 27233-27360/location.hive W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000002e/n/armeabi-v7a
02-26 14:45:13.682 27233-27360/location.hive W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000002e/n/armeabi
02-26 14:45:13.682 27233-27360/location.hive W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000002e/GoogleCertificates_GmsCore_prodmnc_xxhdpi_release.apk / 1.0 running in location.hive rsrc of package null
02-26 14:45:13.682 27233-27360/location.hive W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000002e/GoogleCertificates_GmsCore_prodmnc_xxhdpi_release.apk / 1.0 running in location.hive rsrc of package null
02-26 14:46:05.282 27233-27233/location.hive I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 27233 SIG: 9
```

this is the gradle file (thanks mohammad ali for your feedback):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "location.hive"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

all types of help is welcome if you have any tips please share them,
this is my second time using StackOverFlow if you even have feedback about how I can improve my question next time, well that is welcome too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: can u add the gradle library ?

Comment: which one the upper class or the other one?

Comment: MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);  Is "map" id name is correct ?

Comment: abhi20392 can you put you answer down below so that i can make it the correct answer and THANKS A LOT for all the help you all gave me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />



public class MapViewFragment extends Fragment {

    MapView mMapView;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.location_fragment, container, false);

        mMapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mMapView.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately

        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
            if(servicesOK()){
                googleMap = mMap;

                // For showing a move to my location button
                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);
            List<Address> list;
            try {
                list = gc.getFromLocationName(hotel.getAddress(), 1);
                Address address = list.get(0);
                double lat = address.getLatitude();
                double lng = address.getLongitude();
                LatLng latLong = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLong, 15);
                googleMap.moveCamera(update);



                MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                        .title(getString(R.string.landon_hotel) + ", " + city)
                        .position(new LatLng(lat, lng));
                googleMap.addMarker(options);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.error_finding_hotel), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d(this.getLocalClassName(), e.getMessage());
            }
            }
            }



        });

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mMapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mMapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }
     public boolean servicesOK() {
        int result = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

        if (result == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            return true;
        } else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(result)) {
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result, this, DIALOG_REQUEST);
            dialog.show();


        } else {


         Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.error_connect_to_services), 
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       }

        return false;

           }

       }
```